# Getting parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 10

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My GitLab pipeline job is continuously failing. I tried a lot in fixing it however I still get this error:-

```
$ SONAR_STATUS=$(curl -s --fail "${SONAR_INSTANCE}/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=xxx-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" | jq -r '.projectStatus.status')
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 10
```

Here is my code:-

```
artifacts:
  stage: sonarlint
  image: 'xxxx'
  variables:
    SONAR_INSTANCE: ${SONAR_STAGING_URL}
  needs:
    - yyy-merge-analysis
  before_script:
    - env
  script:
    - python /opt/sonarqube/sonar_get_issues.py --sonar_instance ${SONAR_INSTANCE} --sonar_token ${SONAR_TOKEN} --source xx-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --target xx-master --output sonar-issues-report.json
    - python /opt/sonarqube/sonar2codequality_converter.py --file sonar-issues-report.json --output code_quality.json
    - python /opt/sonarqube/sonar_merge_request_report.py --project xxx-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --project_id ${CI_PROJECT_ID} --gl_token $ACCESS_TOKEN --merge_request_id $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID --sonar_instance ${SONAR_INSTANCE} --sonar_token ${SONAR_TOKEN} --issues sonar-issues-report.json
    - SONAR_STATUS=$(curl -s --fail "${SONAR_INSTANCE}/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=xxx-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" | jq -r '.projectStatus.status')
    - echo $SONAR_STATUS
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - sub-components.json
      - sonar-issues-report.json
      - code_quality.json
    reports:
      codequality: code_quality.json
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. I used `-i` while making the curl request to debug it. The curl request was failing and returning 404 page not found due to extra forward slash in it.
After removing the extra forward slash, curl request worked fine with no error in the script.